# Is this the right version of Vim for OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, vim, osx-snow-leopard

I'd like to try Vim. I'm using Mac OS 10.6.2 (Snow Leopard). I downloaded vim7.0.224.tar.bz2 from [here](http://macvim.org/OSX/index.php#Downloading).

However, I have doubts. It's the newest version offered, but the heading says "OS X 10.4 (Tiger)".

Is there another, preferable version I should know about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should definitely check out [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim). It's a port of Vim for the mac, written in Cocoa (like Safari, Mail and many other Mac apps). Regarding Snow Leopard compatibility, the developer says:

> The stable build seems to run fine on Snow Leopard, but please consider using a snapshot instead as they are built specifically for Snow Leopard (the snapshot also runs on Leopard).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that package of Vim for mac is dead.  Try [this one](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the newest version. I'm not sure what the deal with that site is, but it seems to be out of date. MacVim [currently lives at Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) and I'm running 7.2 stable 1.2 successfully on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

Both `MacVim` (the latest snapshot from `Google Code`) and the traditional curses `vim` can be easily installed and kept uptodate via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=vim).

Answer (score 1):

You'll find that vim is included with Mac OS X by default.  Just open up Terminal.app and type 'vim' at the prompt.  There shouldn't be any need to download and install vim on your OS X machine.

Answer (score 0):

note that macvim is gui app and isnt really useful in the way that vim is.
also macports version of vim is missing every useful feature

Comment: This might have been a helpful answer if you'd suggested some specific ways MacVim is less useful or useful features the macports vim is missing.